# How to extract the corresponding text of a Div via xpath?

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

While making xpath to extract data out of the below given HTML nodes, I'm unable to extract the corresponding text from corresponding elements within a Div.

```
<div class="Main">
    <div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">Jack</div>
        <span class="Date">
            <div><span class="Date">6 June 2018</span></div></span></div>
    <div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">Hurley</div>
        <span class="Date"><div><span class="Date">21 June 2011</span></div></span></div>
    <div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">Kate</div>
        <span class="Date">
            <div><span class="Date">11 May 2013</span></div></span></div>
    <div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">John</div>
        <span class="Date">
            <div><span class="Date">5 March 2001</span></div></span></div>
```

What I want is to extract Date text in `<div><span class="Date">` against the text in `<div class="Birth">`. 
The problem in mapping the data extracted data 
['Jack','Hurley','Kate','John']
via 
`xpath('//*[@class="Birth"]/text()').extract()` and 
['6 June 2018','21 June 2011','11 May 2013','5 March 2001'] via 
`xpath('//*[@class="Date"]/text()').extract()`
 is that they are not necessarily going to be in the same order, thus a relative mapping within the div is required as it can be seen that the name of the div class are same for all segments.
For being sure it must be like, For Text element Kate - Date is 11 May 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about siblings but iteration method can work it out as:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
            if list_search[i] == "Jack":
                    Updated = corresponding-value-in-div[i]
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get list of `<div class="Sub">` iterate over them and use relative xpath to get elements of each div

Here an example :

```
subs = response.xpath('//div[@class="Sub"]')
for sub in subs:
     print(sub.xpath('.//div[@class="Birth"]/text()').extract_first())
     print(sub.xpath('.//div/span[@class="Date"]/text()').extract_first())
```

This will return that:

Jack

6 June 2018

Hurley

21 June 2011

Kate

11 May 2013

John
5 March 2001

Comment: But iteration here have a drawback if there are some more elements present in between. For example: if there be a div class="sub" in between with birth text as "ben" and corresponding date being "11 March 1991", But what I only want is corresponding text to 4 given Birth class.Also while yielding the data and exporting it into csv this will create a problem.

Comment: Could you give a real example ? I am not sure to get the problem with the iteration

Comment: For example: If after the Jack div there are 2 more div like:
<div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">James</div>
        <span class="Date"><div><span class="Date">21 June 2011</span></div></span></div>
<div class="Sub">
        <div class="Birth">Wane</div>
        <span class="Date"><div><span class="Date">21 June 2011</span></div></span></div>
But what I wanted was Data for Jack Hurley Kate and John and that too in that order. Also there might be a possibility that Kate div is missing for some case then it must be returned with value not found.

Comment: Currently what I'm doing is try and expect with iteration to map data from the list extracted by using parent node, but there must be a method to capture this via xpath sibling method and that method is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code and instead of directly giving the name "Jack" you can write another xpath for it also.

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(text(),"Jack")]//following-sibling::span/div//text()')
```