# While writing shell script using awk getting error unterminated regexp

Tags: linux, shell, unix, curl, awk

I am trying to to get output of below shell script-

```
curl -k -s --noproxy '*' 'https://confluence.***.**.com/display/abc/xyz' | awk ' /<div id="main-content" class="wiki-content">/ {flag=1;next} /        <\\/div>/{flag=0} flag { print }'
```

after executing it I am getting an error-

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  /<div id="main-content" class="wiki-content">/ {flag=1;next} /        <\\/div>/{flag=0} flag { print }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                 ^ unterminated regexp
```

Can someone help me with resolving this error?

Comment: On a more general note, hoping that there is only one `</div>` is a pretty bold assumption. Don't use regex to parse HTML. (Google "Cthulhu Zalgo HTML")

Comment: Don't bother Googling that Cthulu HTML, because it's not helpful.  Instead, here are some examples of why you don't want to use regular expressions to parse HTML: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html

Comment: @tripleee there are multiple </div> so it is failing and error-
page.tmp:2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
an="1" class="confluenceTd">Release</td></tr></tbody></table></div>

                                                                                                               ^
  Please suggest.

Comment: The usual suggestion is to use a proper HTML parser. A common solution is to use an XPath expression with `xmlstarlet` or similar. But you should probably just accept Ravinder's answer to your actual question and then ask a new question if you still have trouble. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966481/how-to-extract-the-corresponding-text-of-a-div-via-xpath for a start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. Haven't tested it since no samples were shown.

```
curl -k -s --noproxy '' 'https://.......display/abc/xyz' |\
 awk '/<div id="main-content" class="wiki-content">/ {flag=1;next} /        <\/div>/{flag=""} flag'
```

Since `awk` uses only `\` 1 instance of backslashes to escape a character and OP had 2, hence removed it in above code. Changed to `<\/div>` to fix error.

***Other fix in OP's code:***

- Changed `flag { print }` to `flag` we need not to use print with it.
- Changed `flag=0` to `flag=""` so that condition `flag` can be TRUE, we can't set `flag=0` otherwise condition/regexp `flag` will be TRUE for this also which we don't want.

Comment: there are multiple </div> so it is failing and error- page.tmp:2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document an="1" class="confluenceTd">Release</td></tr></tbody></table></div> ^ Please suggest

Comment: @uday, Please paste in code tags what error you are seeing?